# Find the interval of convergence for the given series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\require{cancel}$
Find the interval of convergence for:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n^{1/2})(3^n)}$$

### Progress

I used the **root test**,
$$L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(x+2)^n}{(n^{1/2})(3^n)}}=\frac{x+2}{\cancel{(n^{1/2n})}(3)}=\frac{x+2}{3}$$
Therefore, to discover the interval of convergence I did this:
$$\lvert\frac{x+2}{3}\rvert<1$$
Thus, getting this:
$$-1<\frac{x+2}{3}<1\implies-5<x<1$$

The problem here is, I don't remember how to check if the endpoints converge or not. I tried substituting each endpoint into the original series.

- For $x=-5$, I discovered that it was an alternating series, where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges, but $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ converges [conditionally], assuming $a_n=\frac{(x+2)^n}{(n^{1/2})(3^n)}$.
- For $x=1$, I found that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

How can I determine if the endpoint converges or not? Must it converge (at that $x$ value) absolutely, or conditionally?

Comment: I think you're done, the interval is $[-5,1)$.  It usually converges only conditionally at the endpoints, if at all but that doesn't change the interval of convergence.

Comment: Looks finished. You showed divergence at $1$ and convergence at $-5$. Since $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, the convergence at $-5$ is conditional, not absolute.  Of course we have divergence if $x\lt -5$   and if $x\gt 1$.

Comment: So the endpoint is inclusive if it converges conditionally or absolutely, and otherwise exclusive?

Comment: @null: Your comment above is right.

Comment: @null, one small thing. The endpoint is not what converges, but rather the series is what converges **at** the endpoint.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Would you consider turning your comment into an answer, so this question may be removed from the unanswered que.

Comment: @gebruiker Sure I can do that, can't in this moment but will shortly.

Comment: @gebruiker Sorry it took so long but I have posted my comment as an answer.  Now hopefully the OP will show up to sign off on it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I'm posting my comment as an answer so we can clear this one off the plate.

You're done, the interval is $[−5,1)$.  It doesn't have to converge absolutely at the endpoints and it typically doesn't, it often converges only conditionally at the endpoints, if at all but that doesn't change the interval of convergence.  Conditionally convergent endpoints are still part of the interval of convergence.

Comment: Very nice. I am upvoting, so that is will be removed from the unanswered tab. If it would ever happen again that you post an answer to an old question, with no upvoted answers, you might want to post a link to it in [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers). This may help to attract some upvotes.